# Как $_GET-ом достать строку?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Достаю $_GET-ом id:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$posts = R::load('posts', $id);
```

Ищу url: **/page.php?id=1** — всё работает.

Но если задать любые другие поля кроме id, реакции нету, например:

```
$id = $_GET['url'];
$posts = R::load('posts', $id);
```

**/page.php?url=example** — не срабатывает. В чём может быть проблема и как исправить?

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/614762

Comment: @Ипатьев вы там видите ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Ладно, перефразирую первый комментарий. У вас в таблице posts есть запись с id = "example"?

Comment: @ArchDemon нет. но причём тут id = example, если я гружу столбец "url"?

Comment: `$posts = R::load('posts', $id);` в каком месте данной строки есть хоть какое-то упоминание "url"?

Comment: @ArchDemon ну в переменной $id, разве нет?

Comment: Давненько такой ереси не читал.

Comment: @vladislav_zp, в переменной `$id` значение `example`, а я спросил где `url`